# Symbol of equivalence between two functions except by constant

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

There is a symbol $\propto$ to show that two functions are proportionate to each other. Is there a symbol to show two functions differ by a constant? Say $f(x;y) = 2x + y$, I want something that is like $f(x;y) = 2x$ where equal sign is replaced with that symbol ($y$ is given and hence constant).

Comment: If $y$ is a constant then your function should not depend on $y$. Hence you should just have $f(x)=2x+c$ where $c$ represents this constant. The other function could then be written as $g(x)=2x$. If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ differ only by a constant then $\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{dg}{dx}$.

Comment: Hi, my above example is a simple one but the semi-colon is  suppose to mean that y is given and not a variable. I am trying to find if such a symbol exists so that it will save me from writing + C each time (which is used as something else elsewhere in my notes) and having to define what C is each time.

Comment: To avoid having to explain what $C$ is each time you could write it as:$$f(x;y)=2x+\text{constant}$$